# Pasting text seperated by blank into excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following text from a file (as an example) which is separated with a blank line:

```
text123
text12345

text123456
text1234567
```

How can I paste this into excel so that all the text separated by a blank line will go into its own cell? I tried using the import text wizard but did not see any options, this is office 2010. Standard paste puts each line in its own cell.
Thanks

Comment: When Excel see a crlf (new line char) cursor goes to cell below, so you need to change the new line characters in a way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in two steps.  First in your text editor, do a search/replace operation where you replace two line endings in a row (ie [LF][LF] or [CR][LF][CR][LF]) with some character that doesn't appear anywhere else in the text.  ` for example.  Then import the text file as a csv ('comma separated value') file, and change the separator to the character you chose.

(To easily search/replace without needing to know your line ending type, in most text editors you can simply highlight the two lines (from immediately after the 5 in text12345 to the end of the blank line), and copy/paste that into the search box in the search/replace dialog.)

Edit: Here's how to specify a custom delimiter when importing: [How do you change default delimiter in the Text Import in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/291445/how-do-you-change-default-delimiter-in-the-text-import-in-excel)

Also, this question is probably more appropriate to https://superuser.com/ as it's not really programming related.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps will do it if you are happy for text123 to be on the same line as text12345:

1. Use a 'search and replace' tool (one that supports regular expressions) to replace all **double** line feeds with a unique token. E.g. \n\n -> XXXXXXXX (or \r\n\r\n -> XXXXXXXX)
2. Replace all single line feeds with a space character
3. Replace all unique tokens of step 1. with a single line-feed
4. Paste into excel.