# Properly import all fields from 'Windows Contacts' to Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, csv, vcard, windows-contacts

### **I want to migrate/import ALL information of my contacts to Thunderbird.**

On my Windows 7 system I carefully managed my contacts including birthday, gender, spouses and children. But I'm having trouble to successfully export/import to Thunderbird.

After some research I found out that some information is not even in the .contact (xml) file thus cannot be exported to another format: *children are not saved in the xml.*

There are a couple of options I am aware of, which each has it's drawbacks. And none of them transfer all the data. See my answer.

**Which method is the one with the least loss of information?**

*Specs:

Windows 7 SP1, Thunderbird 45.7.1 for Mac, OS X 10.10*

Comment: Next try for me: Try to compare TB export and Win export files and convert accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

These are the options I'm aware of:

**Migrating via VCF file format and its problems**

- In *Contacts* export to vCards.
- Import via an TB Add-on.

---

- You need an add-on for Thunderbird for this to work: [morefunctionsforaddressbook](https://freeshell.de/~kaosmos/morecols-en.html)
- Some fields will not be imported correctly. In my case the *address* field got filled with the whole address, not just the street, while the *city*, *code* and *country* get filled correctly.

**Migrating via CSV file format and its problems**

- In *Contacts* export to comma-seperated CSV file.
- Import directly in TB address book.

---

- Windows Contacts have to be free of quotation marks ("), otherwise you get a lot of errors and contacts get merged.
- If you aren't using Windows with the american regional settings, you have to change the field delimiter to the comma, because Thunderbird only imports comma-seperated csv's. (See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/291445/how-do-you-change-default-delimiter-in-the-text-import-in-excel))
- All fields from the *Family*-tab are missing.
- Only Standard Email address will be exported.

**Migrating via LDIF/CSV file format using [vcfconvert](https://github.com/thomascube/vcfconvert) tool and its problems**

- In *Contacts* export to vCards.
- Merge vCards with CMD to one: `copy *.vcf all.vcf`
- Use *vcfconvert* to convert VCF file to LDIF.
- Import LDIF with TB address book.

---

- Using vcf files which contain all information, you have to be merged single contact vcf's to one to be able to use the tool.
- The converted files are missing the birthday field or better the field with the bday dates will be displayed as *Custom Field 1* and only the year of birth is filled out correctly. Family relevant information is lost.
- UTF-8 characters might get scrambled.